# Vscode Extension API search all files in workspace by content matches

Tags: angularjs, typescript, vscode-extensions, angularjs-components

**update**
I found it: provideWorkspaceSymbols

What is the API equivalent of the search menu in vscode? The `vscode.worspace.findFiles()`
Signature doesn't match the input fields I have in the menu of vscode.

My problem:
I'm writing an html tag to component match extension for an angularjs 1.x project.
The components class names are listed in imports.ts where the components are registered line by line. This component name is already parsed correct. 
With the found components name I have to search my component folder (about 1300 components) which I solved with a grep request inside a node exec call. 
But I want to use the vscode API for that.

Do have any advises/hints?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct function provideWorkspaceSymbols